# Timezone issue with IOS 9.3.5

Tags: ios, objective-c, timezone

its really strange where it only exist in iOS 9.3.5 the latest release for iOS in August. lets deep on the issue.

i usually use the following to get my date with timezone:

```
NSDateFormatter *ddFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[ddFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
    
NSTimeZone *timeZoneObject = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:timeZoneString];
[ddFormatter setTimeZone:@"Africa/Cairo"];
NSDate *date = [ddFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    
return date;
```

> In iOS 9.3.3 timezone is +02:00
>
> In iOS 9.3.5 timezone is +03:00

Why is it that in the last release of iOS is returning the timezone wrong, what fix i can do, the timezone is just an example here and i use it dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

what are you printing ? If you print date then it will always shows `+0000` because by default date will be return in UTC or GMT, I mean not +/- any hours.

If you are printing timezone directly like,

```
  NSTimeZone *timeZoneObject = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Africa/Cairo"];

NSLog(@"timezone : %@",timeZoneObject);
```

then it must print : `Africa/Cairo (GMT+2) offset 7200`.

So what you are printing in console which gives output like, `timezone is +02:00`, you must doing some mistake.

this string `@“Africa/Cairo”` is also wrong. it should be `@"Africa/Cairo"`, your quotes are wrong and it must not compiled. so how you got output!!!

Comment: its compiled and quotes is correct its just the matter of copy and paste. its compiled.

Comment: now your edited question is fine. In my xcode, timezone is always shows `(GMT+2)` for `Africa/Cairo`

Comment: have you test it on In iOS 9.3.5 ?